# How to unfold a list of int pairs in SQL select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I have the following list of parameters:

```
params := [(p_1, m_1), ..., (p_n, m_n)]  // p_i, m_i : int
```

Now I want to build a query which go trough the list and match parmeters:
(the part after *for* is a pseudocode which I want to write in **PostgreSQL** 9.4)

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE p = p_i AND m = m_i  for (p_i, m_i) in params
```

How to write this query in Go (using [jmoiron.github.io/sqlx](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) or standard `database/sql`)?

```
type Param struct {
    P, M int
}
params := []Param{{1,2}, {3,4}}
// ???
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Go, but in SQL you could use this: `where (p, m) in ( (1, 2), (3, 4), ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, `IN` check should satisfy your needs:

Go over params to generate `IN` part of query:

```
paramStr := make([]string, len(params), len(params))
for i, p := range params {
    paramStr[i] = fmt.Sprintf("(%d, %d)", p.P, p.M)
}
```

Then, join params and execute it:

```
err := dbm.Select(&rows, "SELECT * FROM X WHERE (p, m) IN (%s)",
        strings.Join(paramStr, ","))
```

Here, for select, I used [modl](https://github.com/jmoiron/modl) which is a utility on top of `sqlx`.

Comment: I  think in production one should use `sqlx.In`. But this is a detail now.